# How can i use archive.php for indexing wordpress default posts?

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a wordpress theme. In my theme there are a custom post type 'project'. This 'project' post type using archive.php page to index all projects . I want to use archive.php also for indexing wordpress default posts those are coming from default post type 'post'. How can i do this ??

Comment: archive.php with a default loop should do this automatically unless you are using a custom query or changing the query via pre_get_posts. what is the code of your archive.php?

Answer (score -1):

Try archive-{post_type}.php, but I think it's wrong way.
Read more about templates and CTP [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/)

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, I want to show both blog index and custom post index in archive.php  ,  And i found the solution, it need to override the wordpress default template hierarchy. Thank yo for your reply 

Comment: What a solution, say please. I would used a common taxonomy.

Comment: https://www.bynicolas.com/code/override-template-hierarchy/  here is the solution.